Is wider component spacing on a PCB less noisy?
As a general case is it true that an analog board with components spaced out is less noisy than one with a more compact layout?
I am specifically referring to a 4 layer board with power and ground being the inner layers

I suppose it depends what is considered a general case and what's on the analog board and what kind of analog signals runs there. Inductors may couple to each other, but so do signals with high dV/dt

I think this is too broad and generic to be reasonably answered. For example, do you get worse decoupling if you move a cap away from the noise source? Of course. Do you get less crosswalk if you move traces further apart? Of course. Do you get more inductance if you move the grounding via further away... and so on. It depends.

If components are spaced further, then PCB traces are longer, thus higher parasitic resistance -> more noise.

@Designalog But less crosstalk, meaning less noise! See how this can't be reasonably answered.

@Lundin Indeed, I simply provided a counter to the premise. Also, crosstalk in analog designs is usually from digital, he said analog boards.


As a general case is it true that an analog board with components
spaced out is less noisy than one with a more compact layout?

Generally not true at all.
Consider a tightly spaced design; the inductive loops will be small and magnetic induction from an external interferer is minimized. If you considered capacitively coupled noise from an external interferer the same is also true in that a tighter spacing between components inevitably produces a smaller area that has a lower susceptibility to capacitive interference.
Of course, if your target design is a mixture of digital and analogue (for instance) there are certain spacing (and tracking) requirements that must be met to minimize crosstalk to an acceptable level.
Think also about how we have miniaturized electronics over the past several decades and ask yourself if noise has gone up over those decades or, has performance improved.

Regarding the mixed signal PCB / spacing topic, I found Rick Hartley's video on grounding rather instructive.

Fields attenuate with distance. On the other hand, the larger the loop area, the bigger the antenna.
So, if you have a noisemaker like a DC-DC converter, and a sensitive analog circuit, you'd want to:

Minimize the transmitting antenna: good compact layout of the DC-DC, optimize the hot loop, keeping HF currents local, etc.

Minimize the receiving antenna: keep the critical receiving loops small in the analog circuit.

And put the noise emitter as far away from the receiver as possible.


Intuitively, you'd expect to see a bunch of modules, each having tight compact layouts with a good amount of space between noise sources and sensitive circuits.
This "wasted space" can be put to good use, for example by putting "noise neutral" circuits there, which neither emit a lot of noise nor care about it, or the big copper pour to cool the LDO, the silkscreen logo, whatever.
In addition, the whole ground plane is never exactly at the same potential. Depending on current flowing through it, you may get voltage gradients with high current DC, high frequency noise, etc. Circuits using the ground plane as "0V reference" may disagree on what exactly "0V" is if they each pick up their own at different places. High current paths, return paths, etc, need some thought, along with keeping in mind what exactly "0V" is.
For example if you make a motor controller, putting the input and output power connectors on opposite sides of the board means all the current flows through the whole ground plane. In this case the sensitive circuits like current sense or ADC will probably suffer no matter where they are placed. But if the input and output connectors are on the same side of the board, or any other setup that avoids high current through the ground plane, then putting sensitive circuits further away will definitely reduce the ground noise they see.

While there's lots about having more room on a PCB that can reduce noise, I don't think it's fair to correlate the two directly as a general rule. Let's look at some simple cases.
Firstly, while possibly obvious (and perhaps not what you meant), decoupling capacitors should be placed as close to component pins as possible, so spacing them out can cause more noise. Similarly, as the distance from generation to load increases, the ability of bulk capacitance to smooth out any load ripples decreases.
If we consider a trace that is radiating some noise, increasing the length of that trace may cause it to become a better radiator and increase it's noise. Similarly, a longer trace may pick up more noise from external sources, and if there is cross talk between traces, increasing the length may worsen this.
I think in having more PCB area available might make it easier to adhere to practices that help reduce noise. It might allow for better GNDing, simpler routing ETC, but it's not that more space between components always reduces noise, it just might make it easier to reduce noise.
